# Hibernate dynamic fields

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, java-17

We are designing an application with some cross cutting fields like tenant id, default location id, created timestamp, modified timestamp etc. They need to be added dynamically to entity based on the annotation like @EnableCreation, @EnableTenant. We dont want to use @MappedSuperClass as base enitity since it increases too many extends in entity creation. Is there any way I can modify the base entity on runtime and add some variables based on annotation? also i want to add some filters.

I want to populate the fields during save/update.
Please advice if any one implemented.